# How to put labels on a 3d plot

Tags: plotting, labeling

I'm close, but I'm stuck.

Here's my code so far:

```
data = Import["http://www.powerball.com/powerball/winnums-text.txt", 
   "Table", "HeaderLines" -> 1];

clipped = Take[data[[All, 2 ;; 7]]];

ListPointPlot3D[clipped];

balls = Take[clipped[[All, 1 ;; 6]]];

whiteballs = Take[balls, 10];

sorted = Map[Sort, whiteballs];

p = ListPlot3D[sorted, Mesh -> All, InterpolationOrder -> 0, 
  ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap"]

labels = Graphics3D[Text[ToString@Round[#, 1], #, {0, 0}]] & /@ 
  Take[sorted[[All, 1 ;; 3]]]

Show[{p, labels}]
```

I would like to have the ball numbers placed on top of each of the colored squares, but I'm out of ideas.

Comment: They are here, see [here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/1lei5.png) for a smaller set of data.

Answer (score 3):

**Update:** `BubbleChart` with a custom `ChartElementFunction`:

```
bcdata = MapIndexed[Join[#2, {#1, 1}] &, whiteballs, {-1}]; 
         (* transform data to a form acceptable for BarChart3D *)

ceF[ind_:3, sz_:36, c_:Black][{{xmin_, xmax_}, {ymin_, ymax_},{zmin_, zmax_}}, v_, m_] := 
  Dynamic@Module[{vtc = {{0, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, 1}, {1, 0}}},
    {EdgeForm[{Darker@CurrentValue["Color"], Thick}], 
     FaceForm[Texture[Framed[Style[ToString@(Floor /@ v[[ind]]), sz, Bold, c], 
                      Background -> Lighter@CurrentValue["Color"]]]], 
     Polygon[{{xmin, ymin, (zmin + zmax)/2}, 
              {xmin, ymax, (zmin + zmax)/2}, 
              {xmax, ymax, (zmin + zmax)/2}, 
              {xmax, ymin, (zmin + zmax)/2}}, VertexTextureCoordinates -> vtc]}]
```

Examples:

```
BubbleChart3D[bcdata, ChartElementFunction -> ceF[], 
    ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z, r}, ColorData["TemperatureMap"][z]], 
    BoxRatios -> 1, ImageSize -> 500]
```

[image]

```
BubbleChart3D[bcdata, ChartElementFunction -> ceF[;; 3, 24, Black], 
     ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z, r}, ColorData["TemperatureMap"][z]], 
     BoxRatios -> 1, ImageSize -> 500]
```

[image]

---

**Original post:** Post-processing the output of `ListPointPlot3D` using `Texture`:

```
lpp = ListPointPlot3D[whiteballs, 
         PlotRangePadding -> 1, 
         PlotStyle -> PointSize[.03], ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap", 
         Lighting -> "Neutral", ImageSize -> 500, BoxRatios -> 1]
```

[image]

```
vtc = {{0, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, 1}, {1, 0}};
lpp /. Hue[___] :> Sequence[] /. 
    {sty : RGBColor[__], Point[x_, ___]} :>
      ({EdgeForm[{Darker@sty, Thick}], 
        FaceForm[Texture[Framed[Style[ToString@(Floor /@ x), 64, Bold], 
                                Background -> Lighter@sty]]], 
        Polygon[x + # & /@ {{-.5, -.5, 0}, {-.5, .5, 0}, {.5, .5, 0}, {.5, -.5, 0}}, 
                VertexTextureCoordinates -> vtc]})
```

[image]

Comment: muchos gracias!